# Collecting all youtube comments with using Youtube V3 API (RapidApi)

Tags: python, api, jupyter-lab

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://youtube-v31.p.rapidapi.com/commentThreads"

querystring = {"maxResults":"100","videoId":"there should be videoID","part":"snippet"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "ae815778e2msh25c93008c665d9dp1cbf47jsn220cb71c57c0",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "youtube-v31.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

I am currently working on creating YouTube comment dataset. while I am collecting comments from RapidAPI I can collect all given comments in given videoid. However I have a lot of videoids and I don't want to take them one by one, instead I want to put parameter that takes all the comments  in given videoids' array or videoid dataset so how can I do instead putting videoID one by one, in side  the API. [In the image as you can see there a part that should take the videoID but it only works when I put one videoID on it how can I implement it for multiple videoID's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDP0W.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pull multiple videos at one time.  You will probably have to write a loop to get all of the video comments.